# to keep schedule

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

I could have sworn I heard *keep schedule* on a television show where two people were talking informally about making appointments despite last-minute hiccups. But I can't find the phrase anywhere on the internet. "Keep to schedule", or "stay on schedule" seem to be the acceptable forms among a few others. Can I use *to keep schedule* to mean making all prearranged appointments and going as planned without disruptions?

Comment: No, you can't. You can **keep to schedule** (when you are speaking in general terms) or **keep to the schedule** (when you are speaking of a specific schedule).

Comment: If you "heard it on television" that is like you "read in the newspaper". Neither make it right. And especially on TV you might not quite hear what was said - even if you rewind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The phrase **keep schedule** refers to staying on schedule.

> It would be well within the Shetland's ability to fly a strong
>   headwind from Cairo to Poole,  and also keep schedule as demonstrated
>   in  Chart 8.  [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=mGDmAAAAMAAJ&q=%22keep%20schedule%22&dq=%22keep%20schedule%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjW8LmAk5rbAhVR1lMKHSDVDwUQ6AEIcTAO)
>
> ...Manila Railroad Company (failure to keep schedule) [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=wWw9AQAAMAAJ&q=%22keep%20schedule%22&dq=%22keep%20schedule%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIovSflJrbAhUKD5AKHYIRC9s4FBDoAQhKMAY)
>
> In Kansas City they were told that the Interstate Trail had brought them that far, but from there south they would bump into troubles they never dreamed of and that it would be impossible to keep schedule if they could keep going at all. [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=s9rQe2tM4h0C&pg=RA5-PA26&dq=%22keep%20schedule%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIovSflJrbAhUKD5AKHYIRC9s4FBDoAQhcMAo#v=onepage&q=%22keep%20schedule%22&f=false)
>
> When you do impose a fine in the rather exceptional and unusual cases  on one of these important trains for failure to keep schedule, does that fine not come out of the pocket of the railroad? [link](https://books.google.com/books?id=R4RRAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA223&dq=%22keep%20schedule%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIovSflJrbAhUKD5AKHYIRC9s4FBDoAQhhMAs#v=onepage&q=%22keep%20schedule%22&f=false)

I think it would be fair to say that it is a somewhat dated use.

Comment: Can I say "keep up the schedule"?